# How do I set header and footer in a PDF, from HTML, with knp-snappy-bundle?

Tags: pdf, rendering, wkhtmltopdf, knp-snappy

## Long story short

With `knp-snappy-bundle` I can't generate a header in the PDF, while I can actually generate a footer.

Is it a bug, a feature, or I'm doing something wrong?

## Details

### 1. Environment

I'm testing the `knp-snappy-bundle`, I've also installed the `wkhtmltopdf` binary from `h4cc`. This is part of my `composer.json`:

```
"h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "^0.12.3",
"knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.5",
```

The resulting binary of `wkhtmltopdf` says this:

```
$ vendor/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 --version
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3 (with patched qt)
```

### 2. *Without* headers or footers, it works

I've setup a controller that uses the `knp-snappy-bundle` and **it works:**

This is my `PdfController`:

```
public function downloadPdfAction( string $docName ) : Response
{
    $pdf = $this->getPdf( $docName );

    return new PdfResponse( $pdf, $this->getFilename( $docName ) );
}

private function getPdf( string $docName ) : string
{
    $html = $this->renderView( 'AppBundle:documents:' . $docName . '.pdf.twig' );

    $options = [];

    $generator = $this->getPdfGenerator();
    $pdf = $generator->getOutputFromHtml( $html, $options );

    return $pdf;
}

private function getPdfGenerator() : Pdf
{
    $generator = $this->get( 'knp_snappy.pdf' );

    return $generator;
}
```

It basically:

- Has a `downloadPdf` action that

  - 1. Gets a PDF document by its name, passed in as a parameter. In this example we'll use `'helloWorld'`.
  - 2. Returns a new `Response` created with the content of the PDF, using the `PdfResponse` class in the bundle.
- To  get the PDF

  - 1. it renders a view with the `twig`engine.
  - 2. gets the service (splitted into another function `getPdfGenerator()`).
  - 3. uses the service to `getOutputFromHtml()` with no options passed-in.

This is my `helloWorld.pdf.twig`:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="pdfPageBody">
            <h1>
                Hello, World!
            </h1>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here it is the resulting PDF, exactly as expected:

[image]

### 3. *With* headers and footers, it fails!

So I now add the header and footer. To do so, I just add a couple of twigs, render the HTMLs into a couple of variables, and pass them in into the options of the Pdf renderer:

```
private function getPdf( string $docName ) : string
{
    $html = $this->renderView( 'AppBundle:documents:' . $docName . '.pdf.twig' );

    $header = $this->renderView( 'AppBundle:documents:header.pdf.twig' );
    $footer = $this->renderView( 'AppBundle:documents:footer.pdf.twig' );

    $options = [
        'header-html' => $header,
        'footer-html' => $footer,
    ];

    $generator = $this->getPdfGenerator();
    $pdf = $generator->getOutputFromHtml( $html, $options );

    return $pdf;
}
```

The header and footer are identical one to each other, except for the contained text:

This is my `header.pdf.twig`:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="border: 5px dashed crimson; color: maroon; background-color: darksalmon">
            This is a header
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the `footer.pdf.twig`:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="border: 5px dashed crimson; color: maroon; background-color: darksalmon">
            This is a footer
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And wow!!! The footer gets rendered but the header does not!!

This is what I get:

[image]

To be noted in the image:

1. There is "something" in the header. I can see the text of the page content like "clipped".
2. The footer does not fully render, as it hides all the bottom border-lines, and the text base-line is aligned to the bottom edge of the page.

### Soooo, hence my question!!

- What should I do to get the header rendered as well?
- Should'nt it be that I could see the header rendered in the PDF with this simple setup? Why does it not appear?

Answer (score 7):

Solved!

Well, it seems that `wkhtmltopdf` is really strict to consider the doctype and it does weird things if not.

Inspired here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28343079/1315009

So, I changed all the twigs to include `<!DOCTYPE html>`:

#### helloWorld.pdf.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="pdfPageBody">
            <h1>
                Hello, World!
            </h1>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### header.pdf.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="border: 5px dashed crimson; color: maroon; background-color: darksalmon">
            This is a header
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### footer.pdf.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="border: 5px dashed crimson; color: maroon; background-color: darksalmon">
            This is a footer
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

## Final result

I finally got this:

[image]

It happens to have:

1. The header, with no weird clipping on the body
2. The footer.

Hope to help!

Answer (score 0):

I was still having this issue with my header even after making sure I had DocType set. It turns out it was because I was floating 2 divs in the header. Removed the float styles and it worked. There were still floated divs within the main content of the PDF which didn't cause any issues.